# React Testing Library: useMutation from React Query Not Called in Formik onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, formik, react-query

I'm having an issue with testing a React component that uses Formik for form handling and React Query's useMutation for data submission. Despite setting up mocks and simulating a form submission, the useMutation's mutate function is not being called as expected.

Component Setup:
I've created a custom hook useProfileFormMutation that wraps useMutation. Here's its implementation:

```
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { putProfile } from "../../../services/ProfileService";

const useProfileFormMutation = () => {
    return useMutation((values) => {
        return putProfile(values);
    });
};

export default useProfileFormMutation;
```

And in my EditForm component, I use this custom hook:

```
import React from "react";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import { useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

import { ProfileSchema } from "../../validators/Validate";
import { useProfileFormMutation } from "./hooks/useProfileFormMutation";

const EditForm = ({ setNeedsEdit, data }) => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const userName = Cookies.get("UserName");
    const { mutate } = useProfileFormMutation(); 

    const { firstName, lastName, city, zipCode, bio } = data;

    const userData = {
        userName: userName,
        firstName: firstName === null ? "" : firstName,
        lastName: lastName === null ? "" : lastName,
        city: city === null ? "" : city,
        zipcode: zipCode === null ? "" : zipCode,
        bio: bio === null ? "" : bio
    };

    const backToProfile = () => {
        setNeedsEdit(false);
    };

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={userData}
            onSubmit={(values) => {
                mutate(values, {
                    onSuccess: () => {
                        queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["profile"] });
                        return backToProfile();
                    },
                    onError: (error) => {
                        console.log("query error", error);
                    }
                });
            }}
            validationSchema={ProfileSchema}
            enableReinitialize={true}
        >
            {(formik) => {
                const {
                    values,
                    handleChange,
                    handleSubmit,
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    isValid,
                    dirty
                } = formik
                return (
                    <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
                        <div className="border w-[100%] h-32 md:w-[20%] my-4">
                            <p>profile img</p>
                        </div>
                        <Form
                            className="grid grid-cols-12 grid-rows-min gap-4 my-4 p-2 md:w-[80%] h-[100%]"
                            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                        >
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="firstName"
                                placeholder={firstName === null ? "First name" : firstName}
                                value={values.firstName}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className={`border w-full rounded-lg text-center p-1 col-span-12 md:col-span-6
                                    ${errors.firstName && touched.firstName ? "border-red-500" : "border-lime-500"}
                                `}
                            />
                            {errors.firstName && touched.firstName && (
                                <span className="text-red-500">{errors.firstName}</span>
                            )}
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="lastName"
                                placeholder={lastName === null ? "Last name" : lastName}
                                value={values.lastName}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className={`border w-full rounded-lg text-center p-1 col-span-12 md:col-span-6
                                    ${errors.lastName && touched.lastName ? "border-red-500" : "border-lime-500"}
                                `}
                            />
                            {errors.lastName && touched.lastName && (
                                <span className="text-red-500">{errors.lastName}</span>
                            )}
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                name="city"
                                placeholder={city === null ? "City" : city}
                                value={values.city}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className={`border w-full rounded-lg text-center p-1 col-span-12 md:col-span-6
                                    ${errors.city && touched.city ? "border-red-500" : "border-lime-500"}
                                `}
                            />
                            {errors.city && touched.city && (
                                <span className="text-red-500">{errors.city}</span>
                            )}
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                pattern="[0-9]{5}"
                                name="zipcode"
                                placeholder={zipCode === null ? "Zipcode" : zipCode}
                                value={values.zipcode}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className={`border w-full rounded-lg text-center p-1 col-span-12 md:col-span-6
                                    ${errors.zipcode && touched.zipcode ? "border-red-500" : "border-lime-500"}
                                `}
                            />
                            {errors.zipcode && touched.zipcode && (
                                <span className="text-red-500">{errors.zipcode}</span>
                            )}
                            <textarea
                                spellCheck="true"
                                type="text"
                                name="bio"
                                placeholder={bio === null ? "Bio" : bio}
                                value={values.bio}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className={`border w-full rounded-lg text-center p-1 col-span-12 md:h-32
                                    ${errors.bio && touched.bio ? "border-red-500" : "border-lime-500"}
                                `}
                            >Bio</textarea>
                            {errors.bio && touched.bio && (
                                <span className="text-red-500">{errors.bio}</span>
                            )}
                            <div className="flex justify-center col-span-12">
                                <button
                                    type="submit"
                                    className={`my-4 w-[8rem] h-[2rem] border rounded-full ${!(dirty && isValid) ? "" : "bg-green"}`}
                                    disabled={!(dirty && isValid)}
                                >
                                    Update
                                </button>
                                <button
                                    className="p-2"
                                    onClick={backToProfile}>
                                    Back to profile
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                );
            }}
        </Formik>
    );
};

export default EditForm;
```

Test Setup:
I'm mocking useProfileFormMutation in my test file like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

import EditForm from '.././EditForm';
import { useProfileFormMutation } from '../hooks/useProfileFormMutation';

jest.mock('js-cookie');

jest.mock('../hooks/useProfileFormMutation', () => ({
    useProfileFormMutation: jest.fn((values) => ({
        mutate: jest.fn(values)
    }))
}));

jest.mock('@tanstack/react-query', () => ({
    useQueryClient: jest.fn(() => ({ invalidateQueries: jest.fn() })),
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    Cookies.get.mockReturnValue('mockUserName');
});

describe('EditForm Component', () => {
    const defaultProps = {
        setNeedsEdit: jest.fn(),
        data: {
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Doe',
            city: 'Seattle',
            zipCode: '12345',
            bio: 'A short bio here'
        }
    };
    
    it('submits the form with updated values', async () => {
    render(<EditForm {...defaultProps} />);
    const user = userEvent.setup()

    const firstNameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('John');
    const lastNameInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Doe');
    const cityInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('Seattle');
    const zipcodeInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('12345');
    const bioInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText('A short bio here');

    await act(async () => {
        fireEvent.change(firstNameInput, { target: { value: 'UpdatedJohn' } });
        fireEvent.change(lastNameInput, { target: { value: 'UpdatedDoe' } });
        fireEvent.change(cityInput, { target: { value: 'UpdatedSeattle' } });
        fireEvent.change(zipcodeInput, { target: { value: 'Updated12345' } });
        fireEvent.change(bioInput, { target: { value: 'UpdatedA short bio here' } });
    });

    await user.click(screen.getByText('Update', { name: /submit/i }))

    const { mutate } = useProfileFormMutation();

    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(mutate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({
            userName: 'mockUserName',
            firstName: 'UpdatedJohn',
            lastName: 'UpdatedDoe',
            city: 'UpdatedSeattle',
            zipcode: 'Updated12345',
            bio: 'UpdatedA short bio here'
        }));
    });
});

}
```

Issue:
When I run my test to simulate a form submission, mutate is not being called. The test fails with Expected number of calls: 1, received number of calls: 0.

Question:
How can I correctly mock and test that mutate is called upon form submission with Formik and React Query? Am I missing something in my mock setup or test implementation?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).